# Is there any way to export IM logs from Meebo?

Tags: export, meebo

A web service, a Firefox extension, a desktop program or script, or just about anything will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found many many requests for this feature to be implemented natively, <s>but have not seen Meebo officially release anything</s> and Meebo has officially released a [webpage for downloading chat logs](https://www.meebo.com/chatlog-download).  It works until Meebo Messenger closes on July 11, 2012.

<s>However</s> Also, I have found this:

http://blog.meebo.com/?p=2348#comment-1140779

> A friend Says: 
>   May 20th, 2010 at 1:55 pm
>   I couldn’t get a login for the meebo forum so I’m posting here.
>
> This is how I exported my chat logs from meebo:
>
> Download the iMacros Firefox plugin.
>   Create a macro with this script:
>
> ```
> VERSION BUILD=6000328
> TAB T=1
> SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:chatlogcontent EXTRACT=HTM
> SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\ FILE=MeeboChats.html
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://s.meebocdn.net/skin/default/img/arrow-right.gif
> ```
>
> 1. Navigate to a chat log with a user in meebo.
> 2. Go to the first chat in the history.
> 3. In the iMacros plugin in the Play tab, insert the number of chat log entries under > Repeat Macro Max.
> 4. Press Play (Loop)
>
> This macro goes through the log entries and exports the chats to an html. You can then > rename the html file for the person you chatted with. Repeat 1-4.
>
> Hope this helps someone.

This is untested by myself (I don't have firefox -_-) but it might be of use, even if just for the method of how to get the data out, as this could be converted to greasemonkey, etc.

Comment: Wow, I just tested it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I just thought that I would give a little update to the code. I tried log2log but I think that software is obsolete so don't bother.

I needed to save my logs but unfortunately the code displayed does not work and I assume its  because Meebo has made several changes since then. Anyways, I made a few edits and it worked perfectly. The steps are still the same but here is the new macro:

VERSION BUILD=7401110
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:chatlogcontent EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=**C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop** FILE=MeeboChats.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://s-ssl.meebocdn.net/skin/onyx/img/arrow-right.gif

Make SURE to replace "yourusername" with the current user that your logged in with so that the file is saved to your desktop instead of the c drive.

This is the only change you will need to make.

Create a new macro by hitting record, then stop (this is just to create the file don't do anything). Edit the recorded macro that you just created and delete whatever text is there. Paste in the new code. Replace yourusername save the macro, then follow the steps in the original message to start saving your logs.

Answer (score 0):

[Meebo is offering chat log downloads](https://www.meebo.com/chatlog-download) until [Meebo Messenger closes on 11 July 2012](https://www.meebo.com/support/article/175/).

Additionally, the developer of Log2Log rolled out a [new version of Log2Log](http://deltik.org/news.php?extend.10.7) (v1.0.1) to support conversion of these Meebo chat logs to a different format.  The software can be downloaded [from SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log2log/).